# Starting TabActivity from Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-tabactivity

I am trying to run Activity which extends TabActivity from a class which extends Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TasksTabLayoutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

This is my TabActivity class definition:

```
public class TasksTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity
```

But this obviously wont compile.

I know TabActivity is deprecated but in this case i need to use it.

How can i start TabActivity from my activity?

Comment: Why you think , it is not complete.

Comment: "But this obviously wont compile.?" why it will not compile? are you getting any error?

Comment: ERROR: "The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<TasksTabLayoutActivity>) is undefined"

Comment: So, just from your remarks i see that the problem is starting the intent from view onclicklistener. Happy if someone explain why

Comment: Instead fo this use -> `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `this` in intent constructor pass `<YourActivityName>.this`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TasksTabLayoutActivity.class);
```

Inside `onclicklistener` if you use `this` it refers to the `onclicklistener` class object not the context and the first argument in `Intent` constructor is expecting an `context` to be passed.

You need to supply your `activity` object in this argument(Activity extends context).